# CarrierWave causing json output to become nested on photo key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, carrierwave, jbuilder

I have a weird issue with CarrierWave that I can't find anywhere else.

I'm using Jbuilder to generate the JSON for my API. I have a photos table and a url field on the table.

Without `mount_uploader :url PhotoUploader` on the photos model, my JSON looks like this:

```
"photos": [
            {
              "id": 11,
              "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...",
              "order": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 12,
              "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...",
              "order": 2
            }
          ]
```

But when I add the uploader, my JSON ends up looking like this:

```
"photos": [
            {
              "id": 3,
                "url": {
                  "url": {
                    "url": "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photos/https%3A//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/uploads/folder/photos/img-name.jpg"
                   }
                },
                "order": 2
                },
                  {
                    "id": 2,
                      "url": {
                        "url": {
                          "url": "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photos/https%3A//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/uploads/folder/photos/img-name.jpg"
                        }
                      },
                      "order": 1
                  }
              ],
```

Everything works fine, but the JSON is just so messy looking, and a pain to iterate over. Also, can anyone explain why the URL is so weird looking, repeating itself twice?

Jbuilder code:

```
json.exercises current_user.current_training_week.exercises.uniq do |exercise|
  json.id exercise.id
  json.name exercise.name 
  json.description exercise.description
  json.photos exercise.photos, :id, :url, :order
  json.videos exercise.videos, :id, :url
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the jbuilder template?

Comment: Yep! just added it. @JorgeMarques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arel, if you need to keep same json hash structure, just override :serializable_hash method in your uploader class:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def serializable_hash
    model.read_attribute :url
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. Can you explain is going on in that method?

Comment: Sure. The :model method points to the current instance of your AR model, where you did :mount_uploader . And since the :url method is overriden by CarrierWave, need to use :read_attribute method to get the value of :url attribute of your instance of AR model.

To see hole picture, you may check original whole here https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/serialization.rb

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like `mount_uploader`. CarrierWave will override the read column method and replace it with return an object of your uploader.

So when you try to call url on photo it return you an uploader with url method so it will keep calling url, and get the url value. So there are three url in your json.

But you can still use `url_url` methods get the origin value.

So if you just want to get the specific url, just do like this will be OK.

```
 json.photos exercise.photos, :id, :url_url, :order #url_url is the url column value.
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I ended up iterating over the photos and calling current_path on the url, but this helped me figure out to do that.